# how to capture scroll window in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, capture

In windows we can capture scrolled window using the software SNAGIT

Is there a software or utility that can be used to capture the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `gnome-screenshot` ? It can capture the screen, a window, or an user-defined area and save the snapshot image to a file with delay.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, which wants something that can capture entire scrollable windows.